# Using fread on Linux is returning 0

Tags: linux, fopen, fread

I have written the code below, but I am getting 0 returned from fread. perror returns success so I guess its working OK. But I dont understand why I am not reading the data written to the file.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char wr_buf[4096];
    char rd_buf[4096];
    int i;
    size_t num;

    printf("v1\n");

    fp = fopen("/run/media/nvme/test", "w+");

    if (fp == NULL)
        {
        printf("FAIL\n");
        return -1;
    }

    for (i=0; i<4096; i++)
    {
        wr_buf[i] = i;
        rd_buf[i] = 0;
    }

    num = fwrite(wr_buf , 1 , sizeof(wr_buf) , fp);
    printf("WR num %d\n", num);

    num = fread(rd_buf , 1 , sizeof(rd_buf) , fp);
    printf("RD num %d\n", num);
    perror("fread");

    for (i=0; i<4096; i++)
    {
        if (wr_buf[i] != rd_buf[i])
        {
            printf("ERR %x != %x\n", wr_buf[i], rd_buf[i]);
        }
    }   

    fclose(fp);

    printf("DONE\n");

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fwrite` advances the file position, so by the time you `fread` it is pointing at the end of the file.  If you want to read back the data you just wrote, you have to `fseek` back to the start of your data.

Comment: Yes, I just realized myself that it will be at the end of the file. Thanks

Comment: Also, `fwrite` may not actually write anything.  You'll need to fsync or fclose the file to ensure that data is actually written to the file.  (A flush is not necessary if you seek and read in the same process, though.)

Comment: Thanks I will do that

Answer (score 1):

Call `rewind(fp);` between the fwrite and the fread, to seek back to the beginning of the file. To seek to an arbitrary byte offset,  use fseek instead of rewind.